# Remove a div when no text inside but has another div inside using CSS or Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a Jquery or CSS solution. I want to remove or not display a div and it's contents in the DOM when there is not text content inside div.formHelp but still has div.arrow inside. For example (should NOT display):

```
<div class="formHelp animated bounceInRight">
<div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Example 2 (SHOULD display since there is content inside):

```
<div class="formHelp animated bounceInRight">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id congue libero, non porttitor ligula.
<div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried in terms of jquery / css? To my knowledge, there isn't a way to do this with plain old css, but could do so with a css precomplier.

Comment: @geekth No. Your link doesn't contain the answer to the current one.

Comment: @wahwahwah I am curious on how you would do this with SCSS. I use that a pre-compiler. For CSS I was considering using the pseudo class :empty but the `div.formHelp` is not empty so that does not work.

Comment: @Brandon - please post that as a new question with the specifics (SASS - SCSS)

Answer (score 1):

If there are *no* text contents within the divs you want to hide, this is simple: take the element's `text()`, then `trim()` out whitespace, and see if there's anything left.   If not, you can remove or hide the element.

```js
$('.formHelp').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim().length === 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.formHelp {border: 1px solid}

.arrow {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formHelp animated bounceInRight">
  <!-- no contents -->
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="formHelp animated bounceInRight">
  Has contents
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

(If instead you want to hide divs which contain no text on their own, but which contain child nodes that *do* have text, it gets a bit more complicated; in that case you'd need to filter the contents based on node type as in @gaetanoM's answer.)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this so, but you need to use listener like a `document.onload`. Since it's only a snippet it cannot use it. So don't forget about it.

```js
let divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')];
  console.log(divs);
  divs.forEach((e)=>{
    if (!e.innerHTML) {
      e.classList.add('none');
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>Here is a text</div>
<div></div>
```

Also as I found below you can use

```
div:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This won't work for the question posed here: child nodes still count as innerHTML.